How can I solve the LoRa config tool error?
I am using a LoRa E22 900T22S but could not configure the parameters. I have errors like "module not response" in the config tool. How can I solve this problem? Can you help me?


I want to configure the parameters of the LoRa module but problems like "module not response" appear.

If you haven't tried this before, I would recommend you to check if the status pins M0 and M1 are set to Low and High voltage levels respectively. This sets the LoRa into configuration mode. Connect M0 to Gnd and M1 to VCC. If you are using a LoRa HAT, you can use jumpers to make these connections. Also if you are using Raspberrypi compatible LoRa, you need to make connections as shown in the pictureLoRa Settings to configure parameters
